# can't start master node on apache spark 1.4.1 (without hadoop)

Tags: apache-spark, jvm

I am trying to run spark 1.4.1 without hadoop (spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz) on my ec2 instance.

This is my full log

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -cp /home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop/sbin/../conf/:/home/ec2-user/spark-1.4.1-bin-without-hadoop/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.2.0.jar -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip ip-172-31-24-107 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated?

**NOTE:** I got around this issue installing spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around this issue installing spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.